# How to know number is including specific digit without converting string?

Tags: algorithm, numbers

For example i want to find numbers including 2,7 from 1 to 7000 without converting string.
2 7 12 17 ... 20 21 22 23...7000
Is there a good algorithm with math?
thank you in advance...

Comment: In the title you ask how to check if a number contains a given set of digits. In the question body you ask for the all the number from 0 to n with this digits. Which one do you need?

Comment: @Matteo My goal is question. But, your answer helped me. thanks. Could you give me some advice how to improve algorithm skill.? When i see the algorithm problem, I can't do anything~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that

```
while ( n > 0 ) {
   digit = n % 10;
   // check the digit
   n = n / 10;
}
```

Example with 523

1. In the first iteration you will have digit = 3 (123 % 10)
2. In the second iteration you will have digit = 2 (12 % 10)
3. In the third digit = 5 (5 % 10)

Comment: I think this will still not answer the OP's question. Still it is a little improvement, though

Comment: @izomorphius Actually it answers the question in the title. But you are right the question text is different seems more "how do I find all the numbers from 0 to n containing a set of digits".

Answer (score 2):

Consider that if you put Matteo's code on a loop, it works.
By the way you can improve performance skipping obvious numbers.

For example if you find 7 on third digit like 15783, you can skip all 127XX (they are all valids!) and you can go to 15800

You can also directly build them. From 1 to 7000 they are:

```
xxx2 xxx7
xx2x xx7x
x2xx x7xx
2xxx 7000
```

Replacing `x` with 0-9 digit. (taking care of overlapping like xxx2 = xx7x for 0072 or 0172 ...)

EDIT:

TIP: You don't need strings to do this.  1332 == 1 * 10^3 + 3 * 10^2 + 3 * 10^1 + 2 * 10^0